# How to combine in a (fractional) factorial design model the blocking effect with a treatment (package planor)

Tags: r, experiment-design, blocking, fractional-factorial, split-plot

For my greenhouse experiment with potted trees, I am planing a **fractional factorial design**. The experiment has six factors (treatments) each with two factor-levels, and I want to use a model/package, which creates me the right experimental design (factor combination; blocking). Currently, I am using the package **‘planor’**, but any other package would be also fine to solve my problem.
Here some information about the experiment:

Factors 1 to 5: are nutrients (factor levels: present/absent) and leaf wetness (wet/dry).

Factor 6: temperature (ambient/hot)

Since I have to simulate the temperature/hot factor in a climate chamber, including the combinations with factors 1-5, I have to consider the temperature-factor, as a blocking-factor. **My problem: treatment-, and blocking-factor are combined**. I can use two climate chambers resulting in 4 blocks:
block 1 = hot, block 2 = hot, block 3 = ambient, block 4 = ambient.

So far as I know, it should be possible to specify this  by using the hierarchy-, and base-arguments of planor (see below). 
However, I was not able to combine block and temp. Maybe I am using also the wrong model to describe my experiment properly?
For the statistical analysis I prefer to use a liner mixed-effect model

Here, the R code:

```
library(planor)

trial.fac1 <- planor.factors( factors=list(
                               Block=c(1,2,3,4),
                               N=c("low","high"),
                               Mg=c("low","high"),
                               Mn=c("low","high"),
                               S=c("low","high"),
                               temp=c("ambient","hot"),
                               wet=c("dry","wet"),
                               hierarchy=(~temp/Block)
                               ))

mod1 <- planor.model(model= ~ Block+(N+Mg+Mn+S+temp+wet)^2,   estimate=~N+Mg+Mn+S+temp+wet)

key1  <- planor.designkey(factors = trial.fac1, model = mod1,
                                  nunits = 32, base = ~Block+temp )

Des <- planor.design(key1[1], randomize = ~temp/Block)

print(Des@design)
```

Comment: This is called a split-plot design!